# "ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER A" doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

When I execute `ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER A` it gives out following error.

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Cannot alter the role 'A', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Here [ALTER ROLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775.aspx) it mentions that;

> Limitations and restrictions
>
> You cannot change the name of a fixed database role.

But I can't find any relationship to this with the error. What I'm trying to do is adding a  member not changing the fixed role name.

Any support in resolving this matter is highly appreciated

Comment: I tried both sp_addrolemember and ALTER ROLE. But non of them worked. Between, "sp_addrolemember" is deprecated. I'm using sql server 2016.

Comment: Are you certain you have permissions to run the `ALTER`? Because, what you have should work. Or, the database user `A` doesn't exist (more likely the case).

Comment: The user is already created. But I'm not sure if this is a permission issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error message given the SQL that you've provided. That error would suggest that you tried to run `alter role [A]…`. Can you provide a full reproduction script?

Comment: `CREATE LOGIN [A] WITH PASSWORD = 0x02003F6C7A9A9677F786B5F3E4E89CFD9233464BB84239352575B80AE9C2AD2134B8B730819CA1EC682E409A636C663675534D279117AF1D5246869F1E1B7EF978B8B0E249A4 HASHED, SID = 0x0D7920B0B559D946A8389E2A9024B93F, DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master], CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF

GO 

ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [A]`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think that you are missing a step. You have a login, but you are not adding the login as a user to the database. All the steps below are what you need. The `CREATE USER` step (a database level call) seems to be missing from your work.

I don't think you need the `CREATE LOGIN`, I just wanted to include that so one could see all it takes to do this.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [A] WITH PASSWORD=N'<password>', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
USE [YourDatabase]
GO
CREATE USER [A] FOR LOGIN [A]
GO 
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [A]
GO
```

Change `YourDatabase` to the proper value before you try this.

Comment: Yes, exactly "Create User" was the missing step. Now it works fine, Thanks a lot Richards

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Actually the problematic part for me was that the `login` must be created in **master** context, but the `user` must be in the related database

Answer (score -1):

First you drop existing user role then use below command:

```
USE Databasename
GO
-- create new role for your s to belong to
CREATE ROLE s
GO
-- add s Role to db_owner
EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember 
    @rolename = N'db_owner',
    @membername = N's';
GO
GO
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But here, you have created a ROLE. I already have list of users to add.

Comment: I used CREATE LOGIN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx